# Deleting Extended ASCII characters from a .txt file Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, ascii, cat, tr, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to generate a list of word frequency from a .txt file, I do not want certain ASCII printable characters and all the Extended ASCII characters to contribute to the word frequency list. Here is my generalized code:

```
cat file.txt | tr -d '[:punct:]' | tr -d '[:digit:]' | tr -d '\33-\64\91-\96\123-\255' | tr ' ' '\n' | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn > Freq.list
```

Also, I had originally tried the segment: `tr -d '[:special:]'`    but received the error: tr: invalid character class `special`

A key part of the code I want is to also make sure that symbols next to each other are deleted, such as: `«•`

Lastly, is there a way to delete single quotations attached to a word? Such that "word or 'word can contribute to word. I've tried `tr -d "\""` and `tr -d '\33-\64'` for that but don't seem to work.

Here is an example of the file.txt:
Â£, is the specific heat per unit volume, «•„ and cr,,
are respectively the thermal and electrical conductivity of the normal region"

Which I want output as:
3 the
2 and
1 volume
1 unit
1 thermal
1 specific
1 respectively
1 region
1 per
1 of
1 normal
1 is
1 heat
1 electrical
1 conductivity
1 are

Comment: Can you show an example of `file.txt` and your expected output?

Comment: added the .txt and desired output to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this file:

```
$ cat file
My hovercraft is full of eels
Min luftpudebåd er fyldt med ål
Mon aéroglisseur est plein d'anguilles
โฮเวอร์คราฟท์ของผมเต็มไปด้วยปลาไหล
Iyéčhiŋkiŋyaŋka čha kiŋyáŋ mitȟáwa kiŋ hoká ožúla!
```

You can remove all the non-ascii with `iconv -ct ascii`:

```
$ iconv -ct ascii < file 
My hovercraft is full of eels
Min luftpudebd er fyldt med l
Mon aroglisseur est plein d'anguilles

Iyhikiyaka ha kiy mitwa ki hok ola!
```

Or transliterate them into unaccented ascii if any with `iconv -t ascii//translit`:

```
$ iconv -t ascii//translit < file
My hovercraft is full of eels
Min luftpudebad er fyldt med al
Mon aeroglisseur est plein d'anguilles
??????????????????????????????????
Iyechi?ki?ya?ka cha ki?ya? mithawa ki? hoka ozula!
```

Comment: OP also wants to delete punctuation and digits.

Comment: My .txt files are 10's of thousands of lines long and there's a bunch of random pairings of letters and hyphened words which may be casualties of the code. But: iconv -ct ascii < file then performing my code seems to take care of rogue quotations, hyphens, and non ascii symbols